# Requesting an Editor of a Conference to inform about paper status before the stipulated date?

Tags: publications, conference

Supposing a conference has a decision date of X (lets say) and a grad school application has a deadline that coincides with that date. Could I request the editor of that conference to inform me about the paper status a few days before the date X so that I may update my CV with paper accepted(if it indeed is) rather than just submitted.

Comment: I'd doubt they will give you answer. I don't think the grad school application success will depend on notice that some conference paper is accepted only.

Comment: @TJK If it's a top conference (in software engineering, the notification day of one such is around the corner), an accepted paper would have a strong impact.

Comment: If the decision has not yet happened, the chance is zero, BTW. If the question is actually about the notification date, rather than the (usually non-publicly disclosed) decision date, I'm not 100% sure.